# DbMigrator.GetDatabaseMigrations shows 0 migrations after switching to other localdb instance but migration history table shows 1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, localdb

My application is using SQL LocalDB for storing some data by using Entity Framework 6.4.

I am new to EF migrations.

I had to create a new sqllocaldb instance as using the default `mssqllocaldb` instance was causing some issues.

After changing the connection string to utilize the new instance, DBMigrator is not able to detect the applied migrations.

When I try to call the below code to update the migrations

```
 if (migrations.Any())
 {
     migrator.Update();
 }
```

It fails with an error saying the mdf file already exists. See the exception stack trace below:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot create file 'C:\ProgramData\Sample\data.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass52_0.<CreateDatabaseFromScript>b__0(DbConnection conn)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass60_0.<UsingConnection>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at LocalDbManager.MigrateDatabase()
```

To debug this I added few logs and collected the value of these properties of DbMigrator:

```
Applied Migrations : 0
Local Migrations: 1 (201902251330258_InitialCreate)
Pending Migrations: 1 (201902251330258_InitialCreate)
```

I tried to open the mdf file using SQL Server Management Studio. The dbo._MigrationHistory table shows one row with 201902251330258_InitialCreate MigrationId.

Could somebody please help me solve this issue? Am I missing something here?